# Logout in tabbarcontroller in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I m pretty much new to objective-C and I m doing an app in which on startup of App,a tabbarController with Search and Login views will be presented.When I click on Search tabbaritem SearchView wil appear.When Login tabbaritem is clicked Login view will appear ..When the Login is successful a tabbarcontroller with Four tabbaritems(Search,  Profile,Activities,Logout)will appear.Now when I click on logout I have to logout of the account and I need to show again the startup view..

How can I do it..?I couldnot get ...

When login is successful I m writing this code.

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
      SearchViewController *searchViewController=[[SearchViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SearchViewController" bundle:nil];
       Profile *userprofile=[[Profile alloc]initWithNibName:@"Profile" bundle:nil];
        userprofile.title=@" Profile";

   Activities   *activities=[[Activities alloc]initWithNibName:@"Activities" bundle:nil];

        activities.title=@"Activities";

tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchViewController,userprofile,activities, nil];  


        [self presentModalViewController:tabBarController animated:NO];
```

Now I want to add another tabbaritem as Logout and when it is clicked I want to load a tabbarcontroller with Searchview and LoginView again..How?

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write below code on tapping logout

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```